# Blank screen in PhoneGap?

Tags: android, iphone, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have prepared one application using phonegap.

My application collecting data from server. Data may be above 500 records, first time i am displaying 10 records.

Bottom of the page have four buttons (first, previous, next and last): when user click on next button, next 10 records will be display. If the user wants to filter the records just click on filter button it will move to filter screen. The user can select the filter options and click on submit button, related records will be display. It is working fine.

My problem is when come back from filter screen i have displayed related records, after device keep it side 2 or 3min and click on last button displaying blank screen when drag the screen records is displaying.

Comment: please post some code and post the problem exactly..

Comment: i have add alerts for test purpose,it is working fine.

Comment: i am not able to find where the problem?

Answer (score 0):

When you come back from filter screen at that time just add array with your images and set to delegate methods of `UITableView` or `UICollectionView` and reload your `UITableView` or `UICollectionView` which you use to display image and data

Comment: when reload the page it is displaying first records...but i want to display last records

Answer (score 0):

Every time when you come back reload the page with data array.